# Using AWK to search another data file while looping key file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

I need to search the contents of one file in another.

Tried `grep` but I want the index column in target file:

```
grep -oFf file1 file2
```

**Source File:**

```
1   /data/user/parent_dir_1
2  /data/user/parent_dir_2
```

**Target File(Tab Delimited):**

```
     Dir_name                                    size
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_1                  100066
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_2/sub_child_1      465456
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_2/sub_child_2      54564564
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_2/sub_child_3      464645645
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_3/sub_child_1      45454
/data/user/parent_dir_2                          1313134
/data/user/parent_dir_3                          1313134
/data/user/parent_dir_4                          1313134
/data/user/parent_dir_5                          1313134
/data/user/parent_dir_6                          1313134
```

**Expected Result:**

```
    Dir_name                                      size      Index
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_1                  100066      1
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_2/sub_child_1      465456      1
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_2/sub_child_2      54564564    1
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_2/sub_child_3      464645645   1
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_3/sub_child_1      45454       1  
/data/user/parent_dir_2                          1313134     2
```

**So far I have**

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{k[$1]=1;next;} FNR==1 || k[$1]' Source_File Target_File
```

but for some reason, it only prints the header of Target File, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues:

1. `-F,` is out of place since your data is not comma delimigted
2. Source file's first column is only a substring of target file's first column. You need to use `index` function for that.

You may use this `awk`;

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==NR{k[$2]=$1;next;} FNR==1{print $0, "Index"}
{for (i in k) if (index($1, i)) 
{print $0, k[i]; break}}' Source_File Target_File | column -t
```

```
Dir_name                                     size       Index
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_1              100066     1
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_2/sub_child_1  465456     1
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_2/sub_child_2  54564564   1
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_2/sub_child_3  464645645  1
/data/user/parent_dir_1/child_3/sub_child_1  45454      1
/data/user/parent_dir_2                      1313134    2
```

Comment: Thanks.. now I can see the results.... How do I also catch the Index from my source file in my output?

Comment: Thanks again. It is exactly what I am look'n for. I have to check why the process is getting killed when I run it though. My Target file is Huge. ~20Million records.

Comment: The script was taking a quite a bit of time, but did not produce any result. I am trying to use combination of output of the awk output without Index as the input for the one with Index. That way, the total rows to process goes down from 20M to 7M. Fingers crossed. But, any idea if the latest awk is supposed to take long time?

Comment: If `Target_File` is huge then split into smaller chunks and then run `awk` command